# Suppress Sentry Logs

Tags: javascript, logging, next.js, sentry

I'm using Sentry in my dummy Next.js application (create-next-app). On each app startup or reload, Sentry makes POST requests to their server and after a few calls, this fails and returns 429 error.

This annoys me. I'm using free-plan.

Sentry config (client/server)

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs'

Sentry.init({
  dsn: process.env.sentryDsn,
  enabled: true,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  beforeSend(event) {
    return event
  },
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
})
```

index.js file (default setup)

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {

  return (
   ...JSX
  )
}
```

As you can see, I did not import Sentry in my component, yet it fires requests regardless.

[image: Sentry network requests]

Target route:

```
Request URL: https://xxxxxxxx.ingest.sentry.io/api/xxxxxxx/envelope/?sentry_key=<my-sentry-key>&sentry_version=7&sentry_client=sentry.javascript.nextjs%2F7.7.0

Request Method: POST
```

Is there any way that I can disable these automatic requests?

Comment: Are you saying you're using sentry in dev mode? That seems like a big waste of sentry logs. Why don't you only init your sentry on deployed websites?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I disabled sentry in dev mode in the meantime

Comment: @MirzaLeka how do you disable sentry in dev?

Comment: @MikeDoudkin
This should help:
https://gist.github.com/MirzaLeka/d709d0925d9b749d1b9068abf4b5ad50

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, Sentry will automatically send logs from your app, but you can reduce the number of logs by configuring `tracesSampleRate` in the configuration file.

This goes from 0.0 to 1.0 (float). 1 means that Sentry will capture all logs sent from your app. Lowering the amount reduces the number of logs in Sentry. When set to 0, no automatic log will be sent to Sentry.
However, every manual call to Sentry, e.g: `Sentry.captureException(<EXCEPTION>)` will be displayed in Sentry logs regardless of value of `tracesSampleRate`.

For development purposes, `tracesSampleRate` is set to 1, but for production, Sentry recommends lowering this amount, e.g. to 0.2.
With lower `tracesSampleRate`, fewer logs will be sent to Sentry and fewer console errors (429) will occur.

More on this in the Sentry Docs:

- [Link1](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/performance/)
- [Link2](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/tracing/distributed-tracing/)

There is also a rate-limiting option for business plan users.